# Why was this answer locked?

Tags: support, specific-question, locks

In an effort to better understand the goings-on of the site, I'd like to know why the [accepted answer on this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247879/is-there-a-benefit-to-building-the-larger-versions-of-stores) was locked. It seems to be an appropriate answer, but now I am not able to upvote it.

I understand this may seem like a duplicate question, but all locks may not have the same reasoning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was locked to prevent a rollback war, and to prevent users from defacing the post, which you can see in the edit history.

Unfortunately, locking a post locks all aspects, including votes, but sometimes it's necessary when people are feeling destructive.

Comment: Ah, the edit history does tell the story. Thanks. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: @TimS., this appears to be a user backlash, after an incident [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11147/i-asked-a-question-that-they-didnt-know-how-to-answer-so-they-flagged-it).

Comment: IMO, the problem was solved, no?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I've unlocked the post now, as the main issue has been resolved.